# 14 Bit RGB to YCrCb

Tags: matlab, image-processing, color-space

I have a 14 bit image that I like to convert to YCrCb color space. As far as I know the conversions are written for 8-bit images. For instance when I use matlab function rgb2ycrcb and I convert it back to rgb then it would be all whites. It is very important for me to not lose any information. What I want to do is to separate luminance from chroma and do some process and convert it back to RGB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YCbCr standard to convert quantities from the RGB colour space was specifically designed for 8-bit colour channel images.  The scaling factors and constants are tailored so that the input is a 24-bit RGB image (*8-bits per channel.  BTW, your notation is confusing.  Usually you use **xx-bit RGB** to represent how many bits **in total** that is required to represent the image*).

One suggestion I could make is to rescale your channels independently so that they go from `[0-1]` for all channels. `rgb2ycbcr` can accept floating point inputs so long as they're in the range of `[0-1]`.  Judging from your context, you have 14 bits representing each colour channel.  Therefore, you can simply do this, given that your image is stored in `A` and the output will be stored in `B`:

```
B = rgb2ycbcr(double(A) / (2^14 - 1));
```

You can then process your chroma and luminance components using the output of `rgb2ycbcr`.  Bear in mind that the components will also be normalized between `[0-1]`.  Do your processing, then convert back using `ycbcr2rgb`, then **rescale** your outputs by `2^14 - 1` to bring your image back into 14-bit RGB per channel.  Assuming `Bout` is your output image after your processing in the YCbCr colour space, do:

```
C = round((2^14 - 1)*ycbcr2rgb(Bout));
```

We round as this will most likely provide floating point values, and your image colour planes need to be unsigned integers.